# angular no me toma el valor del input

Tags: angular

Hola estoy haciendo mi carrito de compras para aprender angular y tengo el siguiente problema... No me estaría reconociendo mi valor numero del input, en el que yo pongo por ejemplo la cantidad "3" y siempre se me queda en valor 0 como que no aumenta el input y por lo tanto mi variable de mi arreglo de objetos "cantidad" tampoco aumenta. entonces yo cuando lo agrego a mi carrito de compras siempre mi cantidad es 0... alguna solución donde pueda estar el error? gracias!!!

Esta es mi funcion en el servicio.

````
  let items: Productos = this._ShopList.find((v1) => v1.Nombre == item.Nombre)!;
  if(!items) {
    this._ShopList.push({ ... item});
  } else {
    items.cantidad += item.cantidad;
  }
  console.log(this._ShopList);
  this.ShopList.next(this._ShopList);
}```


HTML: 
```<div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="DownQuantity()">-</button>
                <input size=40 style="width:30px" type=»number» [(ngModel)]="cantidad">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"(click)="upQuantity()">+</button></div>```



link github: https://github.com/JoaquinPavon/AngularProblema
````

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega lo que tienes en el archivo `.ts` de tu componente donde hace uso, del mismo modo, también agrega el `.html` De esta manera aumentas las chances de obtener respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: método find retorna 1 solo elemento, si quieres varios tienes que usar filter, además tu variable "items" es de tipo productos que es 1 solo objeto no una lista, según yo debería ser Producto[], pero esto es especulación ya que no conozco tu código

Comment: Hola!! Gracias por las recomendaciones chicos. Que parte del TS, me recomiendas subir fredy?

Comment: Hola LPZadkiel...  te entiendo lo que me decis pero no me doy cuenta bien... Dejo mi link de github con este "minitrabajo" a ver si consigo ayuda... gracias chicos.. https://github.com/JoaquinPavon/AngularProblema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el enlace de los datos. Con `[cantidad]="item.cantidad"` se le pasa el valor al componente hijo pero no se está recuperando el valor que el componente hijo emite.

Para que funcione en doble vía hay que colocarlo así:

```
<td><app-input-number [(cantidad)]="item.cantidad" [max]="item.Stock" *ngIf="item.Stock" (maxReached)="maxReached($event)"></app-input-number></td>
```

Y en el componente hijo cambiar el nombre de la propiedad `cantidadCambio` a
`cantidadChange` quedando así:

```
export class InputNumberComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() cantidad!: number;
  @Input() max!: number;
  @Output() cantidadChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() maxReached: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  DownQuantity() {

    if (this.cantidad > 0)
      this.cantidad--;
    this.cantidadChange.emit(this.cantidad);

  }

  upQuantity() {
    if (this.cantidad < this.max) {
      this.cantidad++;
      this.cantidadChange.emit(this.cantidad);
    }
    else {

      this.maxReached.emit("se alcanzó el max");
    }

  }
}
```